# How to send HTTP headers to static directory in Connect (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, node.js-connect

I have a simple connect server that serving a directory. I want to send a custom HTTP header to all the files it serves. Here is my code now:

```
 var connect = require('connect');

 var app = connect()
     .use(connect.static('public'))
     .listen(3000);
```

How can I send a header to each page in the public directory (or even every page served by the server)?

(For curiosities sake, I'm trying to send 'x-frame-options' to each page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: write your own middleware to send the headers, or use a lib.
[Helmet](https://github.com/evilpacket/helmet) is a middleware that implements several security headers, including x-frame.
Your code would look something like:

```
 var app = connect()
     .use(connect.static('public'))
     .use(helmet.xframe('allow-from', 'http://example.com'))
     .listen(3000);
```

To add your headers manually, withouth any extra lib, you could do something like this by writing your own middleware:

```
function addMyHeaders(req, res, next){
  res.setHeader("X-My-custom-header", ":{D");
  next();
}

var app = connect()
     .use(addMyHeaders)
     .use(connect.static('public'))
     .listen(3000);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I keep getting this error though -- https://gist.github.com/streetlight/6512105 -- do you know why this would happen? (I'm going with your second option, but have tried both)

Comment: Okay, i fixed the error by using .setHeader instead of .header, but still can't get it to work fully -- only is adding on some files I believe. Will keep this thread up to date! Thanks again

Comment: My fault, .header is an express method, you should use .setHeader when using connect. The other error was the order in which the middlewares were used. I'm editing the answer to reflect this!

Comment: Sounds great! I actually just discovered this myself was going to update the post. Thank you so much for your help again!